# Running a specific Clojure namespace-function?

Tags: function, namespaces, clojure

Is there a way to cause the clojure-launcher (i.e. the wrapper around `clojure.main`) to run a specific function from a certain namespace (I'm looking for a solution that does not require AOT-compiling the namespace and calling its main-function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call namespace's main function (or any other function) withtout AOT just pipe,

```
(use 'ns)
(fn)
```

to clojure.main assuming classpath stuff set up correctly.